# Get different result when using R CMD check with Valgrind

Tags: c++, r, valgrind, r-package

I did a package which has a **Rcpp** function computing the intersection of two 3d meshes, and there is an example included in the package. This function firstly checks whether the input meshes self-intersect, and throws an error if one of them does. The example runs without issue. But when I check the package using R CMD check with Valgrind, this example throws the error: the code detects that the first mesh self-intersects (it doesn't). Why is there a different behavior using Valgrind? As far as I understand, this point has nothing to do with Valgrind; if the two R versions are the same then one should get the same behavior, no?

Comment: What hardware? What operating system? What version of Valgrind? What compiler? Valgrind does not implement accurate x87 10 byte floating point, and it does not implement floating point exceptions. There may also be some other differences, but generally the amd64 double precision emulation is fairly good.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Thanks. I use Valgrind with a Github action. Ubuntu 20. The action installs Valgrind, probably it is the latest version. If there is an unefficient numerical accuracy, that is probably the reason. I have a similar problem with another package. I fear that CRAN will not accept that :-/